# using getters and setters with enum class java

Tags: java, enums

If I don't declare `private Type type;` and try using getters and setters I'm always getting some kind of error which, of-course, I don't really understand. It's just a red line for me.
I am just trying to understand why I have to declare a separate variable that I didn't think I needed in order to do this.

Please do ask if I'm missing any information. This is my first question ever!

Below is part of the practice exercise that I'm trying to do:

**Postgraduate.java** that contains extra private data members:

- type: is an Enum called Type, including Research and Coursework;

Implement Java methods in the file Postgraduate.java that include:

- Initialization constructor that assigns values to all data members;
- Public access methods `getType()` that return values of private data members;
- Public update methods `setType(Type newType)` that update values of private data
  members;
- Public overriding method `toString()` that returns of postgraduate information.

```java
public class Postgraduate {
    private enum Type{Reserch,Coursework;}
    private Type type;

    public Postgraduate(Type newtype) {
        Type type=newtype;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type newType){
        type = newType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the syntax error? I don't see any. One logical error I see is that you declare and initialize local variable `type` which won't initialize class variable. Change it to `type=newtype;`

Comment: @ArunGowda  its my understanding that ``` private Type type;``` is a global variable.. i didnt declare any other variables.. and thats my question that why do i need to declare an extra variable to use emun getter setters

Comment: by local variable I meant inside Constructor.  Why are you doing `Type type=newtype;` ?  isn't it supposed to be ` type=newtype;`?

Comment: @ArunGowda oh fair thanks.. i have no idea how that wouldve been wrong but wrong indeed... im confused about the varaible ```type``` thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is a type, the same as a class or an interface is. Hence this line of your code is declaring a type and not a variable:

```java
private enum Type{Reserch,Coursework;}
```

This line of your code declares a [member variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and not a *global variable* (as you stated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265208/using-getters-and-setters-with-enum-class-java#comment129390302_73265208) to your question):

```java
private Type type;
```

Also, as @ArunGowda wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265208/using-getters-and-setters-with-enum-class-java#comment129390341_73265208), you have an error in the code of `Postgraduate` class constructor. The code should be:

```java
public Postgraduate(Type newtype) {
    type = newtype;
}
```

By [convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) enum values are written all upper-case. You also spelt **Research** wrong. Consider the following code:

```java
public class Postgraduate {
    private enum Type {RESEARCH, COURSEWORK}

    private Type  type;

    public Postgraduate(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public String toString() {
        return type.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Postgraduate phD = new Postgraduate(Type.RESEARCH);
        System.out.println(phD);
    }
}
```